# Chrome packaged app using Java plugin

Tags: java, google-chrome, plugins, applet

I am building a chrome packaged app and want to make use of a Java applet. I read in many places that there is a bug which will not allow Java applets to be loaded in chrome due to a proprietary protocol that Java doesn't recognize, namely, chrome-extension://

http://crbug.com/30258

I instead, hosted the java applet on a server alongside an html page that embeds the applet. Then in my packaged app, I am using a sandboxed web view tag to point to the externally hosted page that contains the applet. Through JavaScripts postMessage protocol, I can communicate to the applet indirectly. This worked about a month and a half ago. Since then, I have been unable to have the java applet load in the packaged app. I get Chrome's puzze-piece image and the error message:

*This plugin only works on the desktop*

I have been unable to load the applet as of recent.

Any ideas?

Comment: *"Any ideas?"*  Avoid applets like you might avoid the plague.

Comment: Yea, I'd agree with you but I need powerful local printer control. I'm using the QZ-Print applet.

Comment: Since recently you mean it started with a new java version? Then it might be related to the changes oracle introduced recently to increase the security of java appetls...

Comment: I thought this might be the problem as well, however, I downgraded JRE and found the same results. It took effort to find a downgrade of google chrome, but in doing so I can confirm my suspicion that the issue is with chrome. My temporary (hopefully), workaround was to create a small http based front end to the applet and install the applet on the local machine through a separate install process. This way, I can communicate with the applet using simple http requests.